# Access a different Couchbase host using local Couchbase webpage

Tags: couchbase

After installing Couchbase Server on my macOS, I can access `http://localhost:8091`, and from there I put my credentials to access the cluster located on my machine.

Using the `cbq` cli like `./cbq -e <host> -u <user> -p <password>` I can access the database located on another host with the given credentials.

Using `./cbq -u <user> -p <password>` I can access the same database I accessed on the webpage `http://localhost:8091`.

Can I somehow access the same database I accessed using the first version of `cbq` commmand, but in the webpage? I mean, I want to be able to query my database on another host using the couchbase webpage.

Can I?

Comment: I'm unclear why you can't just load http://<other_host>:8091?

Comment: @GrahamPople that is not available :(

Comment: What is the issue there - anything we can assist with? It doesn't usually make sense for a frontend web UI to talk to a different backend than the one that served it initially, not least due to CORS.

Comment: apparently besides not being able to access the other host's database using webpage as I can using the cli, my credentials are also not allowed to access the webpage, so accessing the other host:8091 with my account is not possible :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, not a use case I've seen before.

However, you might want to look into some of the IDE plugins that have been released this year for Couchbase, that can provide a similar experience to the web console, but they can connect to multiple Couchbase clusters:

- [Couchbase extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Couchbase.vscode-couchbase)
- [Couchbase plugin for IntelliJ IDEs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22131-couchbase) (pretty much everything from JetBrains, including WebStorm, Rider, PyCharm, etc

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for your reply. Well, sadly that is not possible, indeed... That would be amazing tho, considering that we can only access remote databases using the cli or a plugin like the ones you mentioned..